# Please disappear the disappear tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I can't see the use of the [disappear](/questions/tagged/disappear) tag, at best it is a bad example of a Meta tag, so can it be deleted and blacklisted please.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's what it means. [Trogdor was probably just busy all day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102439/trogdor-are-you-hungry-a-selection-of-tags-to-delete). :-)

Comment: I'd like to add the completely unrelated [tag:site] to this "list". It's *very* similar to [tag:web] but even more useless and ill-defined in my opinion.

Comment: @joachim site and web were removed as well

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]